# Event aggregation using Prism 4

Tags: eventaggregator, prism-4

Can someone please confirm whether I am right about event aggregation in PRISM 4?

Is it the case that you cannot subscribe for an event until the event has been published first or am I missing something?

Comment: please stop posting your question titles IN ALL CAPS. it's like shouting. it won't get you any more (positive) attention.

Comment: @Mat: Sorry about that, just a bad habit, noted for the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can subscribe to an event at any time, otherwise the subscriber would need intimate knowledge about the publisher, which would defeat the purpose of the mediator pattern.